# GlobalScope for saving files in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I have scenarios where I need to save some objects to disk. So far I've been doing this with Java's ExecutorService. But I'm now refactoring parts of my code to Kotlin, and was wondering whether I'm handling this right.

So in Java I have a code which goes to my Kotlin functions which are :

```
// Java code calls this function in KotlinUtils.kt:
fun saveFileInBackground(saveObj: Any, fileName: String) {
    GlobalScope.launch {
        saveFile(...)
    }
}

private suspend fun saveFile(data: ByteArray, ...) {
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        var file = File(....)
        if (!file.exists()) file.mkdirs()

        file.writeBytes(data)
    }
}
```

Now I've read this post : https://medium.com/@elizarov/the-reason-to-avoid-globalscope-835337445abc

And I still don't see a reason to avoid GlobalScope in this particular case. These file writes are something that I need on my app level, and they are not something that could be cancelled anytime after I dispatch those calls.

Another option I had in mind it to have the KotlinUtils class implement CoroutineScope and then just call *launch* instead of *GlobalScope.launch*.
On second thought, that's a bit problematic, because it seems that the KotlinUtil would have to be abstract, which it cannot be (it's a @Singleton class using dagger2)

However, I'm fairly new to Kotlin and Coroutines, so perhaps I misunderstood something. 
Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: So what exactly is your question?

Comment: whether there are any problems with my solution with GlobalScope, or should I go for the second option that I mentioned, or perhaps something different altogether?

Comment: There's a bit of a debate going on as to whether `GlobalScope` is appropriate in an Android app for coroutines that should execute even if the user navigates away from an activity/fragment (thereby clearing any viewmodel and its `viewModelScope`). For the short term, use `GlobalScope`, but keep an eye out for Google-endorsed alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

GlobalScope is a singleton and not associated with any Job. This launches top-level coroutines and highly discouraged to use because if you launch coroutines in the global scope, you lose all the benefits you get from [structured concurrency](https://vorpus.org/blog/notes-on-structured-concurrency-or-go-statement-considered-harmful/)

So if you know this and your task is completely independent of everything else in your application. Hereby independent, I mean, you do not want to cancel currently running tasks even if something goes wrong in other parts of your application. In this case, in my opinion, it is fine to use `GlobalScope`

For ex, if you call `saveFileInBackground` task in a loop and even though it fails in one of the iterations, you do not want to terminate the loop and want to continue with the rest of your iterations.

Another thing to keep in mind while using `GlobalScope`, if you mistakenly write wrong code in `GlobalScope`, it will stay there and will not get canceled by other parts of application which means your application will never terminate

Comment: in contrast to my above statement, you will hardly end up in a situation where you would have to use GlobalScope. You can have your own top-level scope and launch top-level coroutines with that and in your application termination code, you can destroy that scope that will make sure you do not leak any coroutines

Comment: thank you. So how would I go about having my own scope for this specific case? And isn't Dagger2 going to be a problem somehow? (having a scope of own..).
Should I somehow make a scope for the KotlinUtils.kt class ?